# Ideal Voltage Source Short Circuited in exam problem

Tags: remote-control, short-circuit

[image: Schematic of the circuit]

V2 in the diagram is the same as Vin,so it is not 5V constant but it follows the graph.

In an exam question I was given the circuit depicted in the image.The prompt went like this:
In the circuit below switches (1) and (2) remain closed for the time period that Vin == 5V.
(a) Calculate the voltage across the capacitor for t>= 0 and graph it.
(b) Relate the time constants of the circuit for t in [10 ms,inf) and explaing their values circuit wise.

My question is what happens when switch 2 closes.The ideal voltage source V2 will be short circuited and then I don't know whether the voltage across its terminals is going to be 0 (short circuit) or 5V as the graph that was given indicates.My professor insists that Voltage source V2 does not affect the circuit and hence we treat it as a short circuit.I will be glad to read your answers.

Comment: -1 for your professor for asking a stupid question.

Comment: Thank goodness we have circuit breakers - I hope your professor is not an experimentalist.

Comment: it's a trick question ... there is no source of `Vin` connected to the circuit ... that means only V2 varies

Comment: It seems to me that my professor "wanted" a voltage controlled switch but couldn't use the notation cause it wasn't taught during the course,so she abused ideal notation.To my understanding this circuit would blow up.Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a dumb quiz with ideal parts, but it would seem to charge up to 5V/R1 then when switches close oscillate as it tries to pull down to 2.5V from R2/(R2+R1) V1  but then the switches open by design rule and then repeats (oscillates), so the design would burn out the contacts if there was any RC load , if the S2 wasn't burnt out already with the infinite current from 0 ohm ideal V2.